# How to Disable Load new tiles in 'route-me' in iPhone

Tags: iphone, dictionary, offline, route-me

When I move out bound of my map. route-me library will download new tiles.
I don't want it. How can I do !?

Comment: I found some solution about this topic by check at RMWebTileImage.m
method name 

 - (void) startLoading:(NSTimer *)timer {}

comment it all.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like what you want is limit the bounds of route-me map so you can try setConstraintsSW function.

for example:

[mapView setConstraintsSW:((CLLocationCoordinate2D){29.699386,34.902534})
                           NE:((CLLocationCoordinate2D){29.829029,35.067673})];